# extjs store proxy not invoking for xtype

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a popup window that has some xtypes, one xtype is a grid and that has a Store but i dont see it invoking any ajax call. Can someone tell me what am i missing?

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.myPopup' {...
....
{
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: 'MyStore',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-users',
            height : 450,
            columns: [{
                header...

...}
```

Store

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 
    model: 'myApp.model.modelA',
    pageSize: 100,
    remoteSort: true,
    autoload : true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'getStatusId',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows',
            successproperty: 'status',
            totalProperty: 'records'        
        }
    },
    listeners : {
        beforeload : function(store, operation, eOpts) {
            ...
            store.getProxy().extraParams = submitParams;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Is the grid visible in the frontend? Can you make a fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: `autoload` -> `autoLoad`.

Your code also doesn't show an instance of the store being created. `store: 'MyStore'` requires an existing store instance with a `storeId: 'MyStore'`.

You probably want something more like:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.myPopup' {...
....
{
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: { type: 'myStore' },
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-users',
            height : 450,
            columns: [{
                header...

...}

Ext.define('myApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 
    alias: 'store.myStore',
    model: 'myApp.model.modelA',
    // ....
});
```

Comment: changed it, still no luck.

Comment: Evan store: { type: 'myStore' } this worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of store and point to it.

```
 var store = Ext.create('myApp.store.MyStore' {
                autoLoad : true,        
            });
..........

    {       xtype: 'grid',
            store: store,
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-users',
            height : 450,

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @evan-trimboli states out you have to either use an excisting store instance or you can use a config. The config will then lead to a new store instance created for you internal.

To use a config to create a store instance on the fly, you need to provide an alias on the store class e.g. `alias: "store.mystore"`.
Now you can reference to it in the store config of the grid class like `store: { type: 'myStore' }`.

Bring it all together below and see also [a running fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cf8).

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.mystore',  // the alias we need for the store config of the grid
    // ...
});

Ext.define('myApp.view.myPopup', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: {
        type: 'mystore' // references the store by it's alias
    },
    // ...
};
```